# DWF Viewer Library - Android

Tags: android, autodesk

I want to create an Android app which needs to open DWF files within the app and I don't want to launch any other app to view them. I have not found any DWF viewer libraries that can be integrated with our app as in case of PDF, libraries are available.

I came to know that Auto Desk provides DWFToolkit that let developers to create our own DWF Viewer with C++ libraries. But I am not familiar with C++ and I have no idea to proceed.

I wonder some applications(like DWGSee) are available in PlayStore to view DWF files and How have they would have created them.

Please provide your suggestions and help me out.

Comment: Unsure of what you are trying to achieve here , can you provide more detail or some code of what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the [Autodesk View & Data](http://developer-autodesk.github.io/), a viewer that can be user on your app on a phone compatible with WebGL (most newer Android devices). Check a [Android sample here](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/workflow-android-view.and.data.api).

The DWF Toolkit it **very hard** to modify and it's intended to manipulate (read/write) files, not for viewing.